# Autofac and WCF .Net 4.0 - loading long running data at startup

Tags: c#, wcf, autofac

I have a WCF service (per call) .Net framework 4.0, and it uses Autofac for Di, with InstancePerLifetimeScope.

There is an internal call that is being made internally inside one operation that is exposed in WCF that has potencial to be done one everytime the app pool recycles, storing it somewhere that is common and fast read for every request. This would reduce the overall times of this operation in more than 90%.

My question is: if it was pure ASP.Net I would use ApplicationState at Global.asax and that's it! But what could I use here instead in order to fulfill my requirement?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to improve the performance of your wcf service so that your request can be processed quickly? What does your pure asp.net mean?

Comment: Yes that's it. As is, for every request, the internal process in analysis performs an HttpWebRequest to an external API that we don't control and is quite slow. Besides, the output of that call does not vary too often. So we are looking for highest performance and thoughput, and that data must be shared between all requests. What I've meant as pure ASP.Net is because I remember back in the day when I was ASP.Net developer we could use Application State in order to persist long term objects that could be loaded for example at application start and checked everytime, shared among all requests